# ffmpeg rotate image shows aliasing and smudging

Tags: ffmpeg, images

I'm using ffmpeg to overlay an image onto another image, meanwhile rotate the image to a certain angle. If there is no rotation, the output looks good to me; if there's any rotation, the edges are showing aliasing and smudging effects.
What am I missing here? Is there a way I can avoid this?

```
# no rotation, looks good
ffmpeg -i bgp.png -i search.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x=100:y=100" output0.png
```

[image]

```
# rotate 10 degree, looks bad
ffmpeg -i bgp.png -i search.png -filter_complex "[1:v]rotate=10*PI/180[r];[0:v][r]overlay=x=100:y=100" output10.png
```

[image]

```
# rotate 10 degree showing all, look bad
ffmpeg -i bgp.png -i search.png -filter_complex "[1:v]rotate='10*PI/180:c=none:ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow'[r];[0:v][r]overlay=x=100:y=100" output10_1.png
```

[image]

the input is here, [bgp.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KWR0BuP2C_iwy5lh0aUauI6pW--eZGH6/view?usp=drive_link) , [search.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k-jJSLOWOQsW6rOVeGlJBL8ml_75lJ6R/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Add `-antialias <method>`

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks for your advice, can you provide an example pls

Comment: Richard, I do not know your list of methods. Check it with `ffmpeg -list_dither antialiases`

Comment: For more information you can consult documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-87

Comment: @Richard Do you intend to overlay the rotated image over a solid color background, or is it just an example? I can think of a solution for solid background (at least solid color at the overlay area), but not for the general case...

Comment: @Rotem Hi, it's just an example, the background could be any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may solve most of the issue by padding `search.png` with transparent background before rotation:

`ffmpeg -y -i bgp.png -i search.png -filter_complex "color=black@0:100x100,format=rgba[c];[c][1:v]scale2ref=w='iw+20':h='ih+20'[c0][v1];[c0][v1]overlay=10:10,format=rgba[padded];[padded]rotate='10*PI/180:c=none:ow=hypot(iw-20,ih-20):oh=ow'[r];[0:v][r]overlay=x=100:y=100:format=rgb" -frames:v 1 -update 1 output10_1.png`

---

- `color=black@0:100x100,format=rgba[c]` - Creates a transparent 100x100 video.
- `[c][1:v]scale2ref=w='iw+20':h='ih+20'[c0][v1]` - Scale the transparent video to the resolution of `search.png` with additional 20 pixels in each axis.
- `[c0][v1]overlay=10:10[padded]` - Overlay `search.png` over the transparent video.
- `[padded]rotate='10*PI/180:c=none:ow=hypot(iw-20,ih-20):oh=ow'[r];[0:v][r]overlay=x=100:y=100` - Rotates and overlay the padded image.

The padded `search.png` look as follows (the chess pattern represents transparency):
[image]

---

Result:
[image]

---

In case we have a solid background color around the overlay position, we can get better results.
Instead of padding with transparent color, we may pad with the background color:

`ffmpeg -y -i bgp.png -i search.png -filter_complex "[0:v]crop='iw/2-5':'ih/2-5':10:10,format=rgba[c];[c][1:v]scale2ref=w='iw+20':h='ih+20'[c0][v1];[c0][v1]overlay=10:10:format=rgb[padded];[padded]rotate='10*PI/180:c=none:ow=hypot(iw-20,ih-20):oh=ow'[r];[0:v][r]overlay=x=100:y=100:format=rgb" -frames:v 1 -update 1 output10_2.png`

Result:
[image]

Comment: This is a nice idea! Is 20 a magic number?

Comment: I think 4 (2 pixels from each side) is enough. Maybe even 2 is enough (1 pixels from each side).

Comment: just had a try, 4 is as good as 20, the output md5 is exactly the same. 
2 is bad though