ffmpeg rotate image shows aliasing
I'm trying to rotate a PNG image in my video using FFmpeg.
The problem is that when I rotate the image, it loses quality, whereas it is perfect when not rotated
ffmpeg -i /data/user/0/com.example.video_editor/cache/file_picker/1722348162570/1000037019.mp4 -i /data/user/0/com.example.video_editor/cache/ba6a5091-5466-4493-b5da-e98728e6279d.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=98.48512369791666:69.125,format=rgba,rotate=-30*PI/180:ow=rotw(-30*PI/180):oh=roth(-30*PI/180):c=none[slidable1];[0:v][slidable1]overlay=215.43958333333333:257.7833333333333" -b:v 1000k -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -preset fast -c:a aac -strict experimental /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.video_editor/files/output_video_1722348412307.mp4


What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried to do so far to resolve this? Also, what quality is lost? Is this an issue of perception, or is there a drop in resolution or other measurable and concrete factor?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@music2myear The same problem as this question, but I couldn't solve it with the answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1804707/ffmpeg-rotate-image-shows-aliasing-and-smudging

Telling us that is some helpful info, but still not enough. How does it not work? Also, this isn't a forum: Your goal right now is to make your question clear and good and complete, which means you need to edit your post to add content to it, enough content that we can CLEARLY understand the problem you are facing.

Try scaling the inputs by a factor of between  3x and 5x before rotating and overlaying. Use the -s switch at the end of your command to reset the resolution.
